# My fragment keeps crashing when it is being refreshed

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity

I want to refresh the fragment on a button click - i.e, destroy the fragment and force recall on `onCreateView()` method. However, it keeps crashing because of a GRRRR `NullPointerException` on the line `fragment.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Frag1");`

This is my code:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class UserListRecycler extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    static UserAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<UserInfo> list;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userlistGUI, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reUsers);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        list = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        // Instantiate new adapter here
        adapter = new MusicRecyclerAdapter(list);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        // Sets the adapter here
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        populateRecyclerList();
    }


    public void populateList(){
        PopulateUsers userList = new PopulateUsers(list, adapter, recyclerView);
        userList.execute();
    }


    public void recallFragment(){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TabOne");
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .detach(fragment)
                .attach(fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

It is the `recallFragment()` method that is causing the issue. I want to recall on `onCreateView()` as that would physically refresh the fragment and redisplay the recyclerview. It is getting `NullPointerException` on `fragment.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TabOne");`. This is my `stack trace`:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
            at lukazs.usersapp.UserListRecycler.recallFragment()(TabOne.java:160)
            at lukazs.usersapp.UserListRecycler$RecommendUser.onPostExecute(TabOne.java:300)
            at lukazs.usersapp.UserListRecycler$RecommendUser.onPostExecute(TabOne.java:306)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
```

This is my `onCreateView()` method:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userlistGUI, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reUsers);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    list = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
    // Instantiate new adapter here
    adapter = new MusicRecyclerAdapter(list);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    // Sets the adapter here
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return rootView;
}
```

**UPDATED XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rLayouts">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listFrag"
        class="lukazs.usersapp.UserListRecycler"/>
    <view
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/usersList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove detach and attach. Just use replace.

Comment: But it is crashing at `fragment.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TabOne");.`!!!! It is saying that the fragment is null when it is not

Comment: It is null, check my answer

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: thanks, but how do I refresh it? I just need that bit

Comment: thanks, but now my app crashes `onCreateView`, because I think there is something wrong with my `xml` file. It doesn't like it when I put the `fragment` tags in the `xml`

Comment: It crashes with a `java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)`

Comment: it doesnt like the ` View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userlistGUI, container, false);`

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: it has problem inflating the xml file. Update your XML file so I can check it.

Comment: I have updated the `XML` file

Comment: lukazs.usersapp.UsersList is kinda wrong though. Your Class name is UserListRecycler but in the XML class it is targeting something else.

Comment: I rectified it and it still crashes

Comment: I give up! Why is everything going against me

Comment: Cause it is not suppose to have that kind of class location. It usually starts with com.companyname.productname.nameoftheproject.ClassName.

In your case, I think you're just entering something in there that doesn't actually exist. It starts with "com" then press "." then try to navigate from there.

Comment: on the leftside of your AndroidStudio click on the Folder "java" you will see something like "com.somethingsomething" copy that then add the ClassName at the end

Comment: I did do that and yet this friggin GRRR stupid IDE says that it is not valid, I have copied the reference properly and have triple checked it too

Comment: my thing has no `com`

Comment: check the leftside again, but this time. Click on the dropdownlist filter and choose "Android" You will be left with two options. "app" and "gradle" click on the app then Choose "java" Check what you have.

Comment: If still no com. Then delete the class="" from the XML try to run the app.

Comment: just delete the class="" in the Fragment tag from the xml.

Comment: i deleted it and it still crashes

Comment: man i am starting to hate android and fragments and programming now

Comment: delete the Fragment Tag for now. See what happens.

Comment: but then the `refresh` code you provided wont work, because it cant find the `fragment` tag

Comment: the page loads which is great because that is what it was doing 3 hours ago - but now I cant refresh the fragment

Answer (score 1):

```
Fragment fragment = new WhatEverFragmentClassYouHave();
```

You set your `fragment` to null that is why you have a null exception.

If you're going to detach and then attach something. Just call `replace()` if you know how to use it.

```
<fragment 
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"

              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" 
              class="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
/>
```

For the Refresh

```
public void recallFragment(){
        Fragment fragment = new WhatEverFragmentClass();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.article_fragment,fragment,"MyFragmentTag").commit();

    }


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userlistGUI, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reUsers);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        list = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        // Instantiate new adapter here
        adapter = new MusicRecyclerAdapter(list);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        // Sets the adapter here
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: How do you use `replace()`? Is my method call right?

Comment: Man it still crashes. What do I do>

Comment: You would need to supply it with the ID where it should go. For example, in your XML file you have `<fragment id="myFragment" ></fragment> <-- just an example, but there is a fragment tag.  `replace(R.id.myFragment,fragment)` So it needs to know where to put the fragment and replace whatever fragment is there already.

Comment: How do I find out my `fragment tag name` anyway

Comment: When adding a fragment, you should always tell it where to put the fragment. I believe that is your problem. You didn't tell it where to be put into, you just think that it will magically add itself in the XML file without knowing where it should be put.

Comment: I don't have this `<fragment id="myFragment" ></fragment>`. I don't have fragment tags

Comment: getFragmentmanager().getTransaction().add(R.id.myFragment,fragment,"myTagForthisFragment"); something like this.

Comment: I think you are right, but where do I add this tag>

Comment: go to your xml file, the one that you inflated for that class. Then try to add <fragment> It should give you a template if not an error, tellling you that it needs an width and height . Don't forget to supply it with an ID.

Comment: what do I put for width and height?

Comment: You can easily just copy one of the components. On design view. just drag an ImageView component to the designer, then go to Text view and replace the ImageView tag with an Fragment tag, case sensitive I think it is lower case 'fragment' just try both. Hard to comment on Phone.

Comment: depends, Just use fillparent for now if you want.

Comment: i have uploaded my `xml` here, i don't know how to edit it could you please help me

Comment: thanks, could you please put up the code for the refresh

Comment: thanks, but now my app crashes `onCreateView`, because I think there is something wrong with my `xml` file. It doesn't like it when I put the `fragment` tags in the `xml`

Comment: Update your stack log error. Make sure you use the class="THELOCATION OF YOUR CLASS FRAGMENT" Double check your class fragment if it has extended to Fragment

Comment: How do I find `The Location of your class fragment`?

Comment: No need to post. You're trying to create a Pointer in your onCreateView

Comment: If you're using onCreateView to declare pointers, you will have an error. Are you using AndroidStudio?

Comment: Yeah I am using Android Studio

Comment: `ALT+INsert` then choose onViewCreated() then move everything but the View class inflater and return view to the onViewCreated()

Comment: but then it is saying that `onCreateView` has to return something

Comment: Add your onCreateView on your question, I will edit it.

Comment: I have updated the question, by the way thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detaching and attaching the fragment, you should either have an API in your fragment that tells it to refresh its content, or you should create a new instance of the fragment and replace the existing instance with the new one. Telling the fragment to refresh itself is obviously more efficient than destroying and creating a new fragment.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry I am new to Android development

Comment: If all you want to do is refresh the contents of your recyclerview, then simply call recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged() in your recallFragment method. You would also need to notify your adapter of what's changed.